# What is wrong with my table header styling?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this inline style on a view:

```
<style>
    .col-header {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #9d9d9d;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

I then have two column headers with this class:

```
<th class="col-header">
    Item Code
</th>
<th class="col-header">
    Item Description
</th>
<th>
    Unit
</th>
<th>
    Quantity
</th>
```

Yet when the table renders, instead of the column header itself being bl;ac text on grey, a whole lot of extra space has an unwanted grey background:

[image]

When I examine one of the styled headers in Chrome dev tools, I can see that none of my rules have be overridden. This is the only styling in the whole project that is introduced by me, and everything else is the default Bootstrap layout used by the project template.

How can I style this table, in particular it's header row, so that each header is a separate block of grey with black text, without merging with adjacent headers?

Comment: Please share all code necessary to create the pictured output

Comment: @MiXT4PE I believe I have: I have the HTML and styling for affected and unaffected column headers. Surely you can't be asking for the code that populates the table?

Comment: @ProfK you haven't. For example there are input boxes in your screenshot that aren't in the given code. Also, it appears your table has border-collapse: collapse specified but that is not given in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the table cells to look as separate blocks, and assuming you don't want the `tbody` rows to have border you should add the following style:

```
.col-header {
  border-right:1px solid #fff; // updated with background color
}
```

As for the extra spacing, the whole table isn't shown in the screenshot and I can only assume that somewhere you have a long header title that wraps and creates the extra spacing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any difference after I added your border rule. But you are correct about a wrapped title causing the extra spacing, thanks.

Comment: Without working code on a fiddle we are going blindly I'm afraid.

Comment: Hm, I guess, using a transparent color was a wrong call, try using the background color (in this case I assume white) and revert back.